# Display table and scrolls

Tags: css

I having problems with getting the scroll bars to appear inside the left and right container.

The scroll bars appears on the body at the moment.

Please see the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pQq45/7/

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="cont">
       <div class="left">
           <div class="rect"></div>
           <div class="rect"></div>
           ...
       </div>
       <div class="right">
           <div class="rect"></div>
           <div class="rect"></div>
           ...   
       </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;        
}

.wrapper {
    display: table;
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 50px 50px 0 0;   
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.cont{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #333333;
    display: table-row;        
}

.left{
    display: table-cell;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    background: #FF0000;
}

.right{
    display: table-cell;
    width: auto;
    height:100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: #00FF00;
}

.rect{
    display: inline-block;
    width: 150px;
    height: 40px;
    margin: 3px;
    background: #660000;
}
```

How can I get the scrolls to appear inside left and right containers, rather than on the body? So it would look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a more complex layout. And you will run intro trouble using table-layout. I'd recommend you to ditch the table layout thing and use the following:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pQq45/19/

```
html, body {
     height: 100%;
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
 }
 .wrapper {
     background-color: yellow;
     height: inherit;
     padding: 50px 50px 0 0;
     box-sizing: border-box;
 }
 .cont {
     background: #333333;
     position: relative;
     height: inherit;
 }
 .left {
     position: absolute;
     left:0;
     top:0;
     bottom:0;
     width: 200px;
     overflow: auto;
     background: #FF0000;
 }
 .right {
     position: absolute;
     left: 200px;
     top:0;
     right:0;
     bottom:0;
     overflow: auto;
     background: #00FF00;
 }
 .rect {
     display: inline-block;
     width: 150px;
     height: 40px;
     margin: 3px;
     background: #660000;
 }
```

Comment: Awesome! Looks and resizes perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE 2**

[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/pQq45/20/)

I think it's because you have `height: 100%`.
Try setting a pixel height and changing `display: table-cell` to `display: block` so that they'll adhere to the height.

It should look like this:

```
.left{
    width: 20%;
    background: #FF0000;
}

.right{
    width: 80%;
    background: #00FF00;
}

.cont {
    height: 100%;
}

.right, .left {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    height:100%;
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is closer http://jsfiddle.net/pQq45/15/ But I would not like this container to have height set in pixels, but to fill all the space.

Comment: Still the same, please see the image preview in my answer, or see the jsfiddle from Nico.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing

```
    overflow-y: scroll;
```

On .right

Comment: It was there originally, my mistake, I updated the fiddle. Please see it is still not working with overflow-y:scroll